# Python : Solve matrix multiplication to find rotation matrix

Tags: python, matrix, 3d, rotation, calculation

I'm looking for a solution to solve a rotation matrix, given some constraints. Given some constraints, such as

```
 |1     0     0  |   |52| = |x1|
 |0   cosθ  -sinθ| x |32| = |y1|
 |0   sinθ  cosθ |   |15| = |19|
```

And

```
 |1     0     0  |   |25| = |x2|
 |0   cosθ  -sinθ| x |16| = |y2|
 |0   sinθ  cosθ |   |10| = |38|
```

How can I solve to find θ, x1, y1, x2, y2? Tried to solve it with a linear solver.

Comment: Are you sure the constraints are right? Cause by solving quadratic equations I got `sinθ = -4.75` and `cosθ = 11.4`, which is impossible.